# Filtering array based on selected object in JS

Tags: javascript

Trying to get the filtered array based on the selected object. How can I loop through `damaged` array which is inside the object and get the resultant array? I tried to add another condition using `.map` but it prints the rest of the items as well.

Below is the snippet

```js
const inventory = [{
  name: 'Jeep',
  id: '100',
  damaged: [{
      name: 'Wrangler',
      id: '200'
    },
    {
      name: 'Sahara',
      id: '201'
    }
  ]
}, {
  name: 'Audi',
  id: '101',
  damaged: [{
    name: 'Q3',
    id: '300'
  }]
}]

const purchasedCars = [{
    car: 'Jeep',
    id: '100'
  }, {
    car: 'Jeep - Wrangler',
    id: '200',
  },
  {
    car: 'Jeep - Sahara',
    id: '201'
  },
  {
    car: 'Audi - Q3',
    id: '300'
  }
]

const selectedCar = purchasedCars[0];

const filterCars = () => {
  const result = purchasedCars.filter((inv) => inv.id === selectedCar.id)
  console.log('result -->', result);
}

filterCars();
```

Expected output is

```
[{
    car: 'Jeep',
    id: '100'
  }, 
 {
    car: 'Jeep - Wrangler',
    id: '200',
  },
  {
    car: 'Jeep - Sahara',
    id: '201'
}]
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do. Why is that the expected output?

Comment: you are not using the `inventory` array in your code. Can you try to explain what you are trying to do a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to read your mind here. Is this what you want?

```js
const inventory = [{
  name: 'Jeep',
  id: '100',
  damaged: [{
      name: 'Wrangler',
      id: '200'
    },
    {
      name: 'Sahara',
      id: '201'
    }
  ]
}, {
  name: 'Audi',
  id: '101',
  damaged: [{
    name: 'Q3',
    id: '300'
  }]
}]

const purchasedCars = [{
    car: 'Jeep',
    id: '100'
  }, {
    car: 'Jeep - Wrangler',
    id: '200',
  },
  {
    car: 'Jeep - Sahara',
    id: '201'
  },
  {
    car: 'Audi - Q3',
    id: '300'
  }
]

const selectedCar = purchasedCars[0];

const filterCars = () => {
  let result;
  const parentItem = inventory.filter((inv) => inv.id === selectedCar.id)[0];
  
  if ("damaged" in parentItem) {
      result = [selectedCar, ...(parentItem.damaged)];
  }
  
  console.log('result -->', result);
}

filterCars();
```

Note that if you can have more nested car types in the `damaged` property you would you to call filterCars recursively and pass in the car object. If you also want to filters items that may also be present in the `damaged` property, then you would first need to use the [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method (before the `filter`).